# Copy file from current folder to folder where .exe installing by Installscript project

Tags: installation, installshield

I am using InstallShield 2011 for creating installscript project,Now the problem is i want to copy some ini file from the folder to the path where my .exe will installed.

Here is the scenario--

I will give our client to a Folder which contain 2 things

- Setup.exe
- ini folder which contain .ini files.

Now I want that when I execute the setup.exe all the .ini file will copy on the location where the setup is install.

I am using now--

```
CopyFile (PACKAGE_LOCATION ^ "ini\\*.ini" , szSDKDirectory );
```

But when I debug **PACKAGE_LOCATION** contain null string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your media type is CD-ROM, you can use SRCDIR.

PACKAGE_LOCATION just for Network Image media type.

Comment: This is not working when I use SRCDIR it contain only the path upto disk1.Why it not contain disk1\ini\file1.ini.

Comment: Hi Kevin!Now I am using SRCDIR and it works fine for the setup which is in the Disk Image Folder,But My client want single exe.SRCDIR not working for single exe.I also use PACKAGE_LOCATION but when debug it contain only "ini\\*.ini"

Comment: Wow! I found the solution.Now I am using GetCurrentDir()

Answer (score 0):

If your media type is EXE you could have also used SETUPEXEDIR